# Django FileField, unable to upload

Tags: django, forms, file, model

I have Class:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        )
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='courses/')
```

And when user is adding new course it prompts me to enter title and to choose file.. After i enter title and choose file, filename appears. When i press Save button, file name dissapears and i get message "This field is required"
Here is my template:

```
<form action="{% url "courses-new" %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <ul>
    {{ form.as_ul }}
  </ul>
  <input id="save_course" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<a href="{% url "courses-list" %}">back to list</a>
```

Comment: please show your views.py and forms.py too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set your form enctype as `multipart/form-data`. Like this:

```
<form action="{% url "courses-new" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

From [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method
>   was POST and the  that posted the request has the attribute
>   `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, `request.FILES` will be empty.

Comment: It worked, now i want when user clicks 'view' next to Course name, to show uploaded file. This is how i stareted: class DetailCourseView(DetailView):
 model = Course
 template_name = 'course/course_view.html'
 fields = '__all__'

 ...... and this is my "index" view... 

<ul>
  {% for course in object_list %}
    <li class="course">{{ course }}
     (<a href="{% url "courses-edit" pk=course.id %}">edit</a>)
     (<a href="{% url "courses-delete" pk=course.id %}">delete</a>)
     (<a href="{% url "courses-view" pk=course.id %}">view</a>)
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

Comment: DetailView has no attribute named `fields`. You should remove it :)

Comment: Thx, but that doesnt answers my 2nd question.. In ListCourseView i get list of all courses and next to it view, edit and delete links, what i want to do is when some1 presses view to open file that was uploaded to that Course. So far clciking on view i get to: /course/view/34/  where 34 is course id(pk). So how can i open its uploaded file directly when clicked on 'view' ? What do i need to do in Class DetailCourseView and what in course_view.html ? Ty in advance

Comment: I've tried this: def show_files(request, pk):
 objects = Course.objects.get(id=pk)
 return render_to_response('course/course_view.html', {'objects': objects},
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))


--------------- MODEL : def display_file(self):
  self.upload.open() 
  return self.upload.file.read().replace('\n', '<br>')
------------- HTML:  <p>
{{objects.name}}
{{objects.display_file}}
 </p>
 -------- I can only open text files and they look kinda ugly

Comment: What you actually want to do here? What problem are you facing? Do you want users to forcibly download the uploaded file?

Comment: I want to when user clicks view link to see uploaded file of that course. With code of previous comment i am able to display text only of text document and its shown with <br> tags.

Comment: Every uploaded file in django has a `url` attribute to it. If you want the url of the file, you are supposed to render `{{ upload.url }}` (assuming `upload` is your filefield.)